# No such column 'QuantityUnitOfMeasure' on entity 'Product2'

Tags: apex, soql, fields, compile-error, product

I'm trying to read Unit of Measure on Product2. But getting compile time error as below.

> No such column 'QuantityUnitOfMeasure' on entity 'Product2'. If you
>   are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c'
>   after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the
>   describe call for the appropriate names.

But in Product entity field seems there.

[image]

Not sure if I am using a wrong field name. In [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_product2.htm) I couldn't find this field though. Can someone help me with reading unit of measure in product using SOQL?

​Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the SOQL query you're currently using?

Comment: @NickCook it happened because of we have been using version 38 in apex class. It seems field is available for Apex query after version 39.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you need to be using API v.39 or higher to access this field. This seems to be part of a new feature, as it doesn't appear in most of the documentation yet. It is mentioned **[here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/Product2/get-product2-id)**, but that's about it.